# How to create alternative graphs automatically?

Tags: graph

Graphs are useful tools to represent some pipe of processes. For example, there are methods to create a graph according to the set of calculations. For example, compilers take instructions and converted them to a graph to optimize code size and speed.
Is there any way to create alternative graphs by defining one of the possibilities?

I mean that the order of the process is not important sometimes. In this case, several graphs represent the same process in a different order. For example, the first graph is the same as the second graph.

```
    DIV
     /\
    /  \
   a    \
         \
         MUL
         / \
        /   \
       /     \
     MUL   SHIFT
     /\      /\
   MUL b    c  d
   / \
  e   f

  a/((e*f)*b*(c<<d))
```

```
    DIV
     /\
    /  \
   a    \
         \
         MUL
         / \
        /   \
       /     \
     MUL    MUL
     /\      /\
    /  \    /  \
   e    b  f  SHIFT
               / \
              c   d
    
a/((e*b)*(f*(c<<d)))
```

In these two graphs, processes are the same with different representations. Can I create all the possible graphs automatically by defining the rules for each process?

Comment: "compilers take instructions and converted them to a graph"  What is the instruction format?  Please provide the instructions matching your example.  What format do you want the graph output in?

Comment: I add a clarification to the post. For this example let's say that the c language is the input instruction format for the compiler.
For the function in the example, it returns  `(a | b) | (c | d)` which is same as `(((a | b) | c) | d)`. a,b,c and d is input.

Comment: So, what you call a 'process' is what is normally called a mathematical operation?  Are you only concerned with boolean operations?

Comment: No, It may not be a boolean operation but assume that we are able to define (we know) the features of each operation like Associative Property, Commutative Property...